# "Cycle Through Windows" Menu Item is Missing

Tags: macos, keyboard, ui

I recently noticed that the normal cycle through windows command was not working in many of my applications — Terminal is about the only one left that would work. I went to go check, and the *Cycle Through Windows* item in the *Window* menu is gone in multiple applications.

I attempted to assign a cycle command ( <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd>, as is normal ) via the Keyboard preference pane (in some vain hope that the missing menu item would have just been invisible), but that did not work either.

I am completely at a loss here, especially as cycling through open windows is part of my normal workflow.

Comment: Are you sure these applications previously had such an option available? Which applications are you talking about?

Comment: Is the option in **System Preferences / Keyboard / Keyboard Shortcuts / Keyboard & Text**? Does it appear if you restore default settings?

Comment: Interestingly, even after fixing the problem as directed by @LauriRanta below, the ⌘` shortcut works again, but the the ‘Cycle Through Windows’ item in the ‘Windows menu’ is still missing— while still being present in Terminal as before. (I rebooted just to be sure.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most applications have never had a menu item for it. I don't know why Finder and Terminal do though.

⌘` should cycle through windows by default, but if it doesn't, check if the shortcut has been disabled or changed in System Preferences.

[image]

Comment: Hm, it was unchecked. I wonder how that happened and why the functionality (and menu item) was still present in Terminal.

I feel rather dense that I didn't see the menu item for it in the preference pane, though… because I looked.